# iOS 10 Core Data In Memory Store for Unit Tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data

For unit tests, I've using something similar to this: https://gist.github.com/aceontech/8860058 to create an in-memory store while testing my core data models. With the introduction of iOS 10, NSPersistentStoreCoordinators are now hidden inside NSPersistentContainers. Has anyone played around with Core Data on iOS 10 and figured out how to initialize something similar? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You **can** continue using the old approach. It's not deprecated, and `NSPersistentContainer` isn't required.

If you want the newer approach, use the new `NSPersistentStoreDescription` class, which handles all the stuff that could be specified when adding a persistent store. You'd do something like

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyModel")

let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { ...
}
```

This new class also includes things like automatic lightweight migration options, etc.

Comment: I had an issue with using the `NSInMemoryStoreType` where the store was failing to load the model definitions. In addition to the code above, I needed to point it to the default configuration by adding:

`description.configuration = "Default"`

Comment: Interesting, and very strange. Thanks for the heads up.